# Php get current active class for menu

Tags: php, html

May i know how set active menu which page something like `page.php?name=about`

```
$a = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

<li<?php if ($a == 'page.php?name=about'){?> class="active"<?php }?>><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>/page.php?name=about" title="About">About</a></li>
```

My class won't active while on `page.php?name=about`

May I know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're looking for:

```
$_GET['name']
```

The $_GET superglobal is how you access variables from the query string.

```
$class = ($_GET['name'] == 'about' ? "active" : "");
echo "<li class=\"$class\">";
```

Comment: thanks Fosco.. I got two options here. BTW $_GET['name'] is required to sanitize?

Comment: If you're not using it in a database query, I don't see why you would sanitize it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the if condition to: `if ($a == 'page.php' && $_GET['name'] == 'about')`

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` only gives you the name of the script. The parameters aren't included. You need to use the `$_GET` array to get parameters (or `$_POST` if they came that way). Try this:

```
<li<?php if ($_GET['name'] == 'about'){?> class="active"<?php }?>><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>/page.php?name=about" title="About">About</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $a definition would need to be as follows to work as you intend

```
$a = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].'?name='.$_GET['name'];
<li<?php if ($a == '/page.php?name=about'){?> class="active"<?php }?>><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>/page.php?name=about" title="About">About</a></li>
```

Alternatively, you can just use

```
if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=='/page.php')
    $a=$_GET['name'];

<li<?php if ($a == 'about'){?> class="active"<?php }?>><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>/page.php?name=about" title="About">About</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<li><a href="page.php" 
    <?php if(strpos(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),'page.php')=='page.php'){
        echo' class="active"';} 
    ?> ><!-- end of opening 'a' element -->
    About</a></li>
```